# Запуск установщика от имени администратора

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Не устанавливается Visual Studio 2017 (чистая Win7 стоят только дрова), просит права администратора для установки.
Сижу над этим второй день, пробовал наверное все возможные варианты запуска:

- UAC отключен
- правой кнопкой, запуск от имени администратора
- запуск от имени другого пользователя (администратора)
- создание в планировщике задания с высшими правами
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Лог установки:

```
2017-06-04T18:41:35 : Verbose : Visual Studio Installer (1.10.30640.0 : update2) ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Installer\\vs_installershell.exe","/finalizeInstall","install","--layoutPath","E:\\vs2017","--in","E:\\vs2017\\Response.json","--locale","en-US","--activityId","d004c802-d519-4f98-826d-95c7f5665399"]
2017-06-04T18:41:37 : Verbose : Creating VS Telemetry Survey
2017-06-04T18:41:38 : Verbose : Received the application ready notification
2017-06-04T18:41:38 : Verbose : Starting ServiceHub Experimentation client.
2017-06-04T18:41:41 : Error : Experiments Ipc Service creation failed.
 error: [undefined] Request locate failed with message: Hub host 'desktopClr', PID: 2244 exited. code: '3762504530'. at undefined
2017-06-04T18:41:41 : Verbose : ExperimentsIpcRpcService listening to ipc channel: ExperimentsProxy
2017-06-04T18:41:41 : Verbose : Experiments Ipc Service started.
2017-06-04T18:41:41 : Verbose : Telemetry Session ID: a2dfac6b-3fd1-4eba-8e59-c15668f4a1a1
2017-06-04T18:41:43 : Verbose : Getting installed product summaries. [installerId: SetupEngine]
2017-06-04T18:41:43 : Verbose : Starting the installed products provider service.
2017-06-04T18:41:43 : Verbose : Starting the products provider service.
2017-06-04T18:41:43 : Verbose : Getting product summaries. [installerId: SetupEngine]
2017-06-04T18:41:43 : Verbose : Starting the installer service.
2017-06-04T18:41:43 : Error : Failed to start the installer service. error: Request locate failed with message: Hub host 'desktopClr', PID: 4484 exited. code: '3762504530'. at undefined
2017-06-04T18:41:43 : Error : Failed to start the products provider service. error: Request locate failed with message: Hub host 'desktopClr', PID: 4484 exited. code: '3762504530'. at undefined
2017-06-04T18:41:43 : Error : Failed to start the installed products provider service. error: Request locate failed with message: Hub host 'desktopClr', PID: 4484 exited. code: '3762504530'. at undefined
2017-06-04T18:41:44 : Error : Failed to get product summaries. [installerId: SetupEngine, error: [object Object] at Error: [object Object]
    at SetupEngineAdapter.handleServiceError (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\lib\Installer\Adapters\SetupEngineAdapter.js:709:19)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)]
2017-06-04T18:41:44 : Error : Failed to get installed product summaries. [installerId: SetupEngine, error: [object Object] at Error: [object Object]
    at SetupEngineAdapter.handleServiceError (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\lib\Installer\Adapters\SetupEngineAdapter.js:709:19)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)]
```

Answer (score 1):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2cecaf27-dfad-4eb8-9467-d3770c5494a7/visual-studio-2017-installation-sorry-the-product-definitions-failed-to-load?forum=visualstudiogeneral

процесс (vs_installershell.exe) не получает достаточного количества Priviledges, в отличие от своего родителя vs_installer.exe

Он так делал:

Таким образом, я скопировал дочерний процесс cmd line w/ parameters, убил дерево процессов и запускал его вручную из повышенной shell:

```
vs_installershell.exe /finalizeInstall install --layoutPath "C:\Distributives\Visual Studio\VS2017CE" --in "C:\Distributives\Visual Studio\VS2017CE\Response.json" --locale en-US --activityId "3672817a-cecd-44d6-bc9b-4a0a577cafd1"
```

Или попробуй в свойствах файла vs_installershell.exe указать запускать от админа.

Comment: Все так же, выполнял такую строку:
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installershell.exe" /finalizeInstall install --layoutPath "E:\\vs2017" --in "E:\\vs2017\\Response.json" --locale ru-RU --activityId "d004c802-d519-4f98-826d-95c7f5665399"`

Comment: Windows 7 SP1 оригинальная? Проблем с Интернетом во время установки небыло? Как устанавливали VS2017 через Интернет или портативную?

Comment: Windows 7 SP1 msdn образ, проблем с интернетом нет, пытался и онлайн и офлайн установщик, все равно не хватает прав, в свойствах папок тоже выставил полный доступ и для вложенных файлов

Comment: Дело было в службах Windows, выставив всем автоматический запуск, установка пошла, но тоже если явно указать запуск от администратора.